# Office 365 APIs Microsoft Graph authentication failed

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, office365, office365api

I registered sample app from [Microsoft graph sample app](https://dev.office.com/Getting-Started/office365Apis?platform=option-dotnet#next-step)

And standard login is working but when I try to make it simplier by using this code:

```
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Settings.AzureADAuthority);

        var token = authContext.AcquireToken(Settings.O365UnifiedAPIResource, new ClientCredential(Settings.ClientId, Settings.ClientSecret)).AccessToken;
```

I get the following error: `Application with identifier '[ClientId here]' was not found in the directory microsoft.com`

```
Setting.O365UnifiedAPIResource = @"https://graph.microsoft.com/";
Settings.AzureADAuthority = @"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
```

Does anyone know what can be the problem?

Comment: Check out your Settings.ClientId, did you replace the [ClientId here] in your project with the Client ID string you get when you register your sample app?

Comment: @Aleksa . I met the same issue as yours before . You could modify your AzureADAuthority as "https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenantName" . Then the code works .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Settings.AzureADAuthority = @"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id or tenant_name}";
```

When acquiring the token by using the client credential (client id + client secret). You should specify the tenant explicitly.

For example:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}

or

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your_domain.onmicrosoft.com}

BTW, as this registration will be for the sample app, it will only have the Mail.Send permission which is delegated permission. To acquire the app token, you also need to grant the app level permission in Azure AD since your are acquiring the app token rather than the user token.

[image]